# Set value of summary links column using CSOM in SharePoint 2013

Tags: client-object-model

We are creating a custom page where we are providing user a control to add summary links. This is a provider hosted app page and we can't use the SharePoint controls there. So, we are giving the users a control (2 textboxes) where they can add Description and Url for each link.  The list has a column of type summary links. What we are planning to do is read these textboxes and add links in summary links column.

Now, the issue is how do we assign the value to a summary links column using managed CSOM? Does it have to be the entire HTML or does it have to be a collection of Hyperlinks? I couldn't find any reference related to this.

Does anybody have any idea? Thanks in advance.